# When changing view navigation panel reset

Tags: navigation

We have a structure of

Main site

```
site1
site2
site3
```

Recent

If I go to site2 it is highlighted but when I change view of the library inside it is reseted to and "Recent" is highlighted.

Is it normal? Can we change it ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is linked to the structure of Our SharePoint Site

Some user's created link in Navigation to the view of library instead of creating pages and then adding library as webpart.